# How to write this math equation into c++

Tags: c++

I don't know how to write the formula given in C++ and I cant use short cuts.  I have to write the code in long version this is what I have so far

```
        4x^3 + 8x^2 + 9x - 18
y = --------------------------
       |7 – x^3| + √(3x^2 + 18)
```

`|  |` means absolute value

It needs to be in a format like this (this is an example from my book):

```
double y = ((-4.0 * pow(x, 3.0)) + (8.0 * pow(x, 2.0) - (9.0 * x) + 18.0)) / (abs(7.0 - pow(x, 3.0)) + (sqrt(3.0) * pow(x, 2.0) + 10.0));
```

Comment: it needs to be in a format like this " this is an example from my book" double y = ((-4.0 * pow(x, 3.0)) + (8.0 * pow(x, 2.0) - (9.0 * x) + 18.0)) /
                      (abs(7.0 - pow(x, 3.0)) + (sqrt(3.0) * pow(x, 2.0) + 10.0));

Comment: Except some sign difference and some value in denominator, your example is correct.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly your question is?

Comment: That `sqrt` seems terminated too early.

Comment: *and I cant use short cuts*  What do you mean by "short cut"?

Comment: `√1/2` does not make any sense. It was better when you had `^1/2`

Comment: When you had `(3x^2 + 18)√1/2` you were multiplying `(3x^2 + 18)` and the square root of `1/2`.  I have edited it to be `√(3x^2 + 18)`

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is very nearly there. However, if I've understood your equation correctly this should be correct.

```
double y = (4.0 * pow(x, 3.0) + 8.0 * pow(x, 2.0) + 9.0 * x - 18.0) / (std::abs(7.0 - pow(x, 3.0)) + sqrt(3.0 * pow(x, 2.0) + 18));
```

Comment: thank you but what is fabs? and can you write it out not including fabs because my class was never taught this

Comment: [`fabs()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs) computes the absolute value of a floating point number.

Comment: You should really use `std::abs` and let overload resolution do its thing.

Comment: @john315 I've included `sqrt(3.0 * pow(x, 2.0) + 18)`. This calculates the square root of `3x^2 + 18`. `std::abs(7.0 - pow(x, 3.0))` computes the absolute value of `|7 - x^3|`. `cmath` is a header file. You need to include it at the beginning of your program with `#include <cmath>`.

Comment: i forgot to mention that the  |  | means absolute value;   (...)1/2   means square root

Comment: @john315 Why did you attempt to edit my answer? What is it that you do not understand?

Comment: sorry kavanagh i forgot to mention that theres a sqrt 1/2 there and i forgot to add it cause it looked like division instead of sqrt sorry

Comment: @john315 Yes and in [my second comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590456/how-to-write-this-math-equation-into-c/32590782?noredirect=1#comment53035754_32590782) I've shown you where I've used `sqrt()`. You may need to scroll across the equation in my answer to see it.

Comment: i fixed my original first post for the correct equation. the answer you gave me is it the updated one including the √1/2 after the (3x^2 + 18). thank you

Comment: @john315 It always included the `sqrt()`. Can you not see it?